# "Cannot resolve constructor" I need help knowing where the program is going wrong

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to update this Spigot plugin but am getting an error from the section that handles chat. I have updated the API and the same section of code works for previous versions so I'm guessing something new is required but I have no idea what.

The relevant library is `craftbukkit-1.16.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT`

> Cannot resolve constructor 'PacketPlayOutChat(net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IChatMutableComponent)'

Here is the specefic segment of code throwing an error in Intellij:

> ```
> public void sendJson(Player p) {
>     ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutChat(ChatSerializer.a(toString())));
> }
> ```

Here is the rest of the java class in case something in it is relevant to the problem.

```
package me.karasumori.applymc.utils.common;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayOutChat;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.entity.CraftPlayer;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JsonBuilder {

    public enum ClickAction {
        RUN_COMMAND, SUGGEST_COMMAND, OPEN_URL
    }

    public enum HoverAction {
        SHOW_TEXT
    }

    private List<String> extras = new ArrayList<>();

    public JsonBuilder(String... text) {
        for (String extra : text)
            parse(extra);
    }

    public JsonBuilder parse(String text) {
        String regex = "[&�]{1}([a-fA-Fl-oL-O0-9]){1}";
        text = text.replaceAll(regex, "�$1");

        if (!Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text).find()) {
            withText(text);
            return this;
        }
        String[] words = text.split(regex);
        int index = words[0].length();

        for (String word : words) {
            try {
                if (index != words[0].length())
                    withText(word).withColor("�" + text.charAt(index - 1));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            index += word.length() + 2;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder withText(String text) {
        extras.add("{text:\"" + text + "\"}");
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder withColor(ChatColor color) {
        String c = color.name().toLowerCase();

        addSegment(color.isColor() ? "color:" + c : c + ":true");
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder withColor(String color) {
        while (color.length() != 1)
            color = color.substring(1).trim();
        withColor(ChatColor.getByChar(color));
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder withClickEvent(ClickAction action, String value) {
        addSegment("clickEvent:{action:" + action.toString().toLowerCase() + ",value:\"" + value + "\"}");
        return this;
    }

    public JsonBuilder withHoverEvent(HoverAction action, String value) {
        addSegment("hoverEvent:{action:" + action.toString().toLowerCase() + ",value:\"" + value + "\"}");
        return this;
    }

    private void addSegment(String segment) {
        String lastText = extras.get(extras.size() - 1);

        lastText = lastText.substring(0, lastText.length() - 1) + "," + segment + "}";
        extras.remove(extras.size() - 1);
        extras.add(lastText);
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (extras.size() <= 1)
            return extras.size() == 0 ? "{text:\"\"}" : extras.get(0);
        String text = extras.get(0).substring(0, extras.get(0).length() - 1) + ",extra:[";
        extras.remove(0);
        ;
        for (String extra : extras)
            text = text + extra + ",";
        text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1) + "]}";
        return text;
    }

    public void sendJson(Player p) {
        ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutChat(ChatSerializer.a(toString())));
    }

    public void sendAllJson() {
        for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())
            sendJson(p);
    }
}
```

I don't know much about java yet, sorry if my question is vague,

Comment: This means the class constructor not expect the object you are passing to it. Could be the version of the package are newer or older then this code expect.

Comment: For this to work, `ChatSerializer.a()` would need to return a subclass of `IChatMutableComponent`, but I guess it isn't. - what is that `a()` method supposed to do?  What does it return?

Answer (score 1):

The `PacketPlayOutChat` constructor isn't excepting the object returned by `ChatSerializer.a()`. It is excepting an `IChatMutableComponent` object.

Read more about java constructors [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/constructors-in-java/)